# Importing components from a module works in the browser, but breaks in tests

Tags: reactjs, import, jestjs

I'm currently writing tests for my `Song` component. The code works as expected in the browser, however, it's breaking in my tests.

Although I've figured out what the issue is and a bad workaround, I don't understand exactly what the problem is and *why* my solution works.

#### The rundown

The `Song` component imports `AlbumArtContainer` and `AvatarContainer`:

```jsx
import AirbnbPropTypes from 'airbnb-prop-types'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'

import './_styles/Song.scss'
import { ListGroupItemLink } from 'Desktop/components/common'
import { Action, ActionList } from 'Desktop/components/common/actions'
import {
  AlbumArtContainer,
  ArtistContainer } from 'Desktop/containers/common/music'

export default class Song extends React.Component {
  // ... redacted code
}
```

I have a `SongContainer` component inside the same directory as `AlbumArtContainer` and `AvatarContainer`:

```jsx
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { songs } from 'Common/api'
import { Song } from 'Desktop/components/common/music'

const mapStateToProps = (state, { id }) => {
  // ... redacted code
}

const SongContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(Song)

export default SongContainer
```

Inside that directory, I have an `index.js` file to export everything:

```js
export AlbumArtContainer from './AlbumArtContainer'
export ArtistContainer from './ArtistContainer'
export SongContainer from './SongContainer'
```

`Song.test.jsx` imports `Song`:

```jsx
import Action from 'Desktop/components/common/actions/Action'
import Song from 'Desktop/components/common/music/Song'

describe("<Song>", () => {
  // ... redacted tests
})
```

Running the test for this file throws the following error:

```
-> % npm run test client/src/Desktop/components/common/music/__tests__/Song.test.jsx

> @ test /home/mightyspaj/Dev/Projects/vibite/client
> jest "client/src/Desktop/components/common/music/__tests__/Song.test.jsx"

 FAIL  src/Desktop/components/common/music/__tests__/Song.test.jsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Invariant Violation: You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received undefined

      at invariant (node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:42:15)
      at wrapWithConnect (node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:101:29)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Desktop/containers/common/music/SongContainer.jsx:19:62)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Desktop/containers/common/music/index.js:1:521)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Desktop/components/common/music/Song.jsx:8:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Desktop/components/common/music/__tests__/Song.test.jsx:2:13)
      at next (native)
      at next (native)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

This is because it's reading `SongContainer`, and `Song` is being imported as `undefined` inside `SongContainer`. This means that `connect()` throws an error when `Song` is passed to it because it expects a component.

But if I import `AlbumArtContainer` and `AvatarContainer` inside `SongContainer` directly from their files instead of their module:

```jsx
import AlbumArtContainer from 'Desktop/containers/common/music/AlbumArtContainer'
import ArtistContainer from 'Desktop/containers/common/music/ArtistContainer'
```

Then `Song` imports correctly inside `SongContainer` and it works just fine. I'm not sure why this is, or why it works fine in the browser but not my tests, so what exactly is the issue here?

I also don't want to import components directly from their file (which is why I import them from their module), so my current solution is only a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From further investigation I realised the issue was due to circular dependencies.

Although it wasn't the solution I'd initially wanted, I've removed the `index.js` files, and have also changed my imports to import components directly from their files using default imports.

This has prevented circular dependencies.